# Compare consecutive columns of a file and determine if any is greater than 80

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file with the output of an SQL query like this:

```
DG_DATA 9 DG_FRA 0 OCR002 3 OCR 3
```

I use the following for extract the columns with numbers

```
awk '{for(x=1;x<=NF;++x)if(x % 2 == 0)printf $x "\t"}'
```

and I get an output with this format:

```
9   0   3   3
```

but I need some help to compare all the integers and print "CRITICAL" if any integer is greater than 80.

Comment: Note that none of the numbers shown is an integer under the normal meaning of the term.  Also, why not simply step over the fields you're interested in?  `for (x = 2; x <= NF; x += 2) printf $x "\t"`?  And don't forget to add a newline to the end: `print ""`.

Comment: Do you have any control over the SQL that produces the output?

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it:

```
{
    n=split($0, arr, " ");
    i=2;
    while(i<=n){
        str=str arr[i]"\t";
        if(arr[i] > 80){
            f=1
        };
        i+=2;
    }
    print str;
    if(f){
        print "CRITICAL";
    }
}
```

---

**EXAMPLES**

All values ok:

```
[llamazing@pc ~]$ echo "DG_DATA 9 DG_FRA 0 OCR002 3 OCR 3"  |  awk '{n=split($0, a, " ");i=2;while(i<=n){str=str a[i]"\t";if(a[i] > 80){f=1};i+=2;}print str;if(f){print "CRITICAL";}}'
9       0       3       3
```

With critical message:

```
[llamazing@pc ~]$ echo "DG_DATA 9 DG_FRA 81 OCR002 3 OCR 3"  |  awk '{n=split($0, a, " ");i=2;while(i<=n){str=str a[i]"\t";if(a[i] > 80){f=1};i+=2;}print str;if(f){print "CRITICAL";}}'
9       81      3       3
CRITICAL
```